# Missing theme file on Jekyll installed with RVM

Tags: macos, themes, jekyll, rvm, minima

I've error when i install Jekyll on MacOS 10.13.2 with 'gem install jekyll' command:

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
```

To solve this problem i am installed RVM and install Jekyll with RVM. Jekyll runs perfectly. But i've some critical problem here. Jekyll comes with default theme named 'Minima'. I want to customize theme, but i check site file, includes file is not here. So can't customize theme.

To find the includes file i use that command on the terminal:

```
which gem minima
```

Output:

```
/Users/bekircem/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/gem
```

So i can't access to includes and other similiar files.

How can i fix that problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a [solution](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues/38#issuecomment-247623675). [Detailed description](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#overriding-theme-defaults) on the Jekyll.org about theme defaults.